# Alternative to $image->copy() in GD module

Tags: perl, svg, gd

I am looking for an alternative to the function `$image->copy` in the GD module.

My current line of code is

```
$image->copy($subimage, 10, 10, 0, 0, $subx, $suby);
```

I am not able to use this function in the [`SVG::GD`](https://metacpan.org/pod/SVG::GD) module. So I am looking for an alternative program that does the same job.

Comment: Why are you unable to use the `copy` method?

Comment: @Borodin SVG::GD doesn't provide a `copy` method. It overrides some of the GD::Font and GD::Image methods by aliasing `*GD::Image::` to `*SVG::GD::Image::` and `*GD::Font::` to `*SVG::GD::Font::`, but there's no `SVG::GD::Image::copy` so you get `Can't locate object method "copy" via package "SVG::GD::Image"`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: That's a nasty way to do inheritance. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have one.

As SVG is a vector format, it's difficult to efficiently copy a portion of an image. Implementing this feature would be difficult, and the `SVG::GD` library hasn't attempted to do so.

If you need this functionality, you'll need to use another library.

Comment: Thanks! My code creates an image using GD module which I would like to have it in SVG format. Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: Not without bigger changes. GD is oriented towards bitmap images, SVG isn't a bitmap format.